# Kubernetes ImagePullSecrets Failing with ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubernetes

I can't get Kubernetes to pull my private docker image.

I have a kubernetes secret called `regcred` in my `default` namespace looking like:

```json
{"auths": {"index.docker.io": {"username": "Username", "password": "Password", "email": "random@email.com", "auth": "VXNlcm5hbWU6UGFzc3dvcmQ="}}}
```

The auth is `Username:Password` b64 encoded.

This is the pod I am trying to create which just fails everytime with `ImagePullBackOff`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: index.docker.io/jor2/hello-world:latest
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

logs:

```sh
Error from server (BadRequest): container "private-reg-container" in pod "private-reg" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled
```

```sh
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  67s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/private-reg to 10.144.195.222
  Normal   Pulling    20s (x3 over 66s)  kubelet            Pulling image "index.docker.io/jor2/hello-world"
  Warning  Failed     17s (x3 over 63s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "index.docker.io/jor2/hello-world": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/jor2/hello-world:latest": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:361849f1befca621043d13cca4e9bee74861754154556e149340a455e53d1d35: not found
  Warning  Failed     17s (x3 over 63s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    3s (x3 over 63s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "index.docker.io/jor2/hello-world"
  Warning  Failed     3s (x3 over 63s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

The secret looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6IHsiaHR0cHM6Ly9pbmRleC5kb2NrZXIuaW8vdjEvIjogeyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ICJVc2VybmFtZSIsICJwYXNzd29yZCI6ICJQYXNzd29yZCIsICJlbWFpbCI6ICJyYW5kb21AZW1haWwuY29tIiwgImF1dGgiOiAiVlhObGNtNWhiV1U2VUdGemMzZHZjbVE9In19fQo=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-04-25T18:59:03Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:.dockerconfigjson: {}
      f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-04-25T18:59:03Z"
  name: regcred
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "270226"
  uid: bbb1310b-421a-4c93-8488-498e7a52095f
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: how does your secret actually look like? You show a json object but not the actual secret. What namespace are you trying to deploy this?

Comment: Be aware `hub.docker.com` is the _web_ ui, `docker.io/jor2/hello-world` is almost certainly the _registry_ version

Comment: @mdaniel i got it working, was ultimately a problem with the specific docker image I was trying to pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with my image and the pod spec needed to be:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: jor2/hello-world:latest
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```